# Can you store a list to a list inside a while loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

I am at the moment of understanding how lists and while loops work in Python. Unfortunately, I am a bit confused with my code.

```
main_list = []
list_1 = [1, 2]
list_2 = [3, 4]

i = 0
n = 2

while i != n:

    number = int(input("Insert a number: "))

    list_1.append(number)
    main_list.append(list_1)
    main_list.append(list_2)

    i += 1

print(main_list)
```

Why am I getting an output of this,

```
>> Insert a number: 2
>> Insert a number: 3
>> [[1, 2, 2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

instead of this?

```
>> Insert a number: 2
>> Insert a number: 3
>> [[1, 2, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

I would appreciate if anyone can explain it to me, thank you.

Comment: I think it changes the list every where where there is a reference of that list

Comment: `main_list` contains `list_1` and `list_2` twice each because that is what you put in it. `list_1` is `[1,2,2,3]` because that is what you put in it.

Comment: You could also run this in http://www.pythontutor.com/  to see each step running visually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the `list1` to `main_list`. So a reference of the `list1` is stored there. So when you change the `list1`, it changes the list every where.

You can create a copy of the list before adding it to the list

```
main_list = []
list_1 = [1, 2]
list_2 = [3, 4]

i = 0
n = 2

while i != n:

    number = int(input("Insert a number: "))

    list_1.append(number)
    main_list.append(list_1.copy())
    main_list.append(list_2)

    i += 1

print(main_list)
```

Comment: @JuventiusKriswijanarko you should accept the answer if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `main_list` contains references to `list_1` and `list_2` and NOT copies of them. To see this clearly add the following lines to the bottom of your code,

```
list_1.append(10)

print(main_list)
```

You will now get the following output,

```
[[1, 2, 2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3], [3, 4]]
[[1, 2, 2, 3, 10], [3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 10], [3, 4]]
```

To stop ths behavior you have to explicitly make copies of the lists using the `copy` library,

```
import copy

main_list = []
list_1 = [1, 2]
list_2 = [3, 4]

i = 0
n = 2

while i != n:

    number = int(input("Insert a number: "))

    list_1.append(number)
    main_list.append(copy.copy(list_1))
    main_list.append(copy.copy(list_2))

    i += 1

print(main_list)
```

Now your output is what you were after in the first place,

```
[[1, 2, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: @JuventiusKriswijanarko if this helped you click the up button or click the tick or click both so other users can see which answers helped.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are modifying `list_1` inside the while loop and appending it to `main_list`. But when you append, only the reference of `list_1`  is added to `main_list`.

Now at the end `list_1` contents are `[1,2,2,3]`. And since `main_list` contains a reference to `list_1`, `main_list` shows the current contents of `list_1` which is `[1,2,2,3]`.

To avoid this, you have to append the contents of `list_1` and not the reference to `main_list`. There are many ways to do it.

One of which is,

> `main_list.append(list(list_1))`

Change your existing line to this.

*Please read this - [Shallow vs Deep Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)*

Answer (score 0):

Your Code:

```
main_list = []
list_1 = [1, 2]
list_2 = [3, 4]
i = 0
n = 2
while i != n:

    number = int(input("Insert a number: "))   
    list_1.append(number)    
    main_list.append(list_1)    
    main_list.append(list_2)    
    i += 1

print(main_list)
```

**After *1st iteration***:

```
main_list = [[1,2,2],[3,4]]
list_1 = [1, 2, 2]
list_2 = [3, 4]
```

**After *2nd iteration***:

```
main_list = [[1,2,2,3],[3,4], [1,2,2,3],[3,4]]
list_1 = [1, 2, 2,3]
list_2 = [3, 4]
```

**what needs to be considered is:** Under the hood python has REFERENCE_TYPE so basically what your **main_list** has is something like:

```
main_list= [
[reference_of_list1],[reference_of_list2],
[reference_of_list1],[reference_of_list2]]
```

so that could be a reason for the issue you're facing.